# How to correctly set selected widget from a list using Provider as state management?

Tags: flutter, dart

I think its best if I describe my scenario just in case you can think of a better solution.

User can have multiple pets and he can choose ONLY ONE skill for his pet from a list.

Here's what I have currently. It is working but I'm not sure if I did this correctly or it may do unnecessary rebuilds specially the widget wrap in `Consumer`

I am using provider as my state management.

Am I on the right track? Every time, the user taps on a skill, it rebuilds **ALL SKILL WIDGET** to change the color of the selected skill? Or is there a better solution for this kind of scenario? Thanks

`pet_state.dart`

```
class PetState with ChangeNotifier {
  Pet selectedPet;
  Skill selectedSkill;

  setSelectedPet(Pet pet) {
    selectedPet = pet;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setSelectedSkill(Skill skill) {
    selectedSkill = skill;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Pet {
  String name;
  Skill skill;

  Pet({this.name, this.skill});
}

class Skill {
  String name;

  Skill({this.name});
}
```

`main.dart`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<PetState>(
      create: (_) => PetState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomeScreen()
      );
    )
  }
}
```

`home_screen.dart`

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget _petBuilder(Pet pet) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Provider.of<PetState>(context, listen: false).setSelectedPet(pet);
        // navigate to skills selection screen
      },
      child: Text(pet.name)
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final pets = [Pet(name: 'pet1'), Pet(name: 'pet2')].map(_petBuilder).toList();
    return Column(
      children: pets
    );
  }
}
```

`skills_screen.dart`

```
class SkillsScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget _skillBuilder(Skill skill) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Provider.of<PetState>(context, listen: false).setSelectedSkill(skill);
      },
      child: Consumer<PetState>(
        builder: (_, petState, __) {
          bool isSelected = petState.selectedSkill?.name == skill.name;

          return Text(skill.name, style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.teal));
        }
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final skills = [Skill(name: 'Skill1'), Skill(name: 'Skill2')].map(_skillBuilder).toList();
    return Column(
      children: skills
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Selector` instead of `Consumer`.

Instead of:

```
Consumer<PetState>(
  builder: (_, petState, __) {
    bool isSelected = petState.selectedSkill?.name == skill.name;
    return Text(skill.name, style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.teal));
  }
)
```

You can do:

```
Selector<PetState, bool>(
  selector: (_, petState) => petState.selectedSkill?.name == skill.name,
  builder: (_, isSelected, __) {
    return Text(skill.name, style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.teal));
  }
)
```

You could go one step further and not rebuild `Text` either:

```dart
Selector<PetState, bool>(
  selector: (_, petState) => petState.selectedSkill?.name == skill.name,
  builder: (_, isSelected, label) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: TextStyle(color: isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.teal),
      child: label,
    );
  },
  child: Text(skill.name),
);
```

This will change the text style when de/selecting it, without actually rebuilding `Text`.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly, what `Selector` does is, it will only rebuild the affected widget? In this case, previously and currently selected widget? Thanks for the extra tip on `DefaultTextStyle`. I can also wrap it with container and have decoration change when de/selecting, right?